# ROS Groovy and Create based TurtleBot dashboard

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Create based TurtleBot, I use the following to bring up the TurtleBot:

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

I then use the following to bring up the dashboard (I can do this on the robot itself or on a workstation with the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME properly set).

rqt -s create_dashboard

The "create_dashboard" comes up, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work as it did in Fuerte.  If I had to guess, it looks like it's reporting Kabuki based information, although I have the Create base and I'm calling "create_dashboard".  However, this is just a guess on my part.  The information in the "Robot Monitor" window is:

Error Device    Message
/Input Ports    Stale
/Kobuki         Stale
/Sensors        Stale

Unfortuantely, my silly karma is insufficient to post a link to how the dashboard looks, but the following may work.

http-colon-//i50.tinypic.com/2j2damf.jpg

It seems strange to me to see the "Kobuki" device -- as if the dashboard is somehow configured to look for Kobuki devices.

Has anyone actually got a Create based TurtleBot running with Groovy?  I assume so since there are so many of them out in the wild.  And if so, what needs to be configured to get correctly get the dashboard working with the Create devices rather than Kobuki devices.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58312/ros-groovy-and-create-based-turtlebot-dashboard/) by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally got the Groovy TurtleBot Dashboard working the Create base by finding the following the page with Google:

https-colon-slash-slash-github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/6

The key is when using the Create base to set the following environment variables on both the robot laptop and the remote workstation:

```
export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect
```

I can then get a working dashboard by running the following on the robot laptop:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

And the following command on my workstation laptop:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard.launch
```

With this, I can now launch the dashboard for the Create based TurtleBot under Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) with karma: 153 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on 2013-07-09**:
I have the same problem, this is my .bashrc, any suggestions?
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.187.116:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.187.116
export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-07-24**:
not working